# Will this indexing work as I think it will?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am a little confused about the indexing I am going to do.

First, I am using a 4-column index, like this:

Index Name - advanced_query

Columns will be used in the index - title, category 1, category 2, category 3

The Indexing Code

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD INDEX advanced_query (`title`, `cat_1`, `cat_2`, `cat_3`, `date_posted`)
```

Okay, so this is how (from what I understand) it will work:

- a query of **title** will use the index.
- a query of **cat_1** will use the index.
- a query of **cat_2** will use the index.
- a query of **cat_3** will **NOT** use the index. So I will create a different index for it.
- a query of **title, cat_1** will use the index.
- a query of **title, cat_1, cat_2** will use the index.
- a query of **title, cat_1, cat_2, cat_3** will use the index.
- a query of **title, cat_1, cat_3** will use the index.
- a query of **title, cat_2** will use the index.
- a query of **title, cat_2, cat_3** will use the index.
- a query of **title, cat_3** will use the index.
- a query of **cat_1, cat_2** will use the index.
- a query of **cat_1, cat_2, cat_3** will use the index.
- a query of **cat_1, cat_2** will use the index.
- a query of **cat_1, cat_3** will use the index.

**TL;DR**

So in this index, only a **query of cat_3** will not benefit from it, right? Thanks!

**Edit**

What query are you doing ? searching a post (it's title and 3 different categories)

What is size of table ? Less than 2 thousand rows

Structure of table ?

```
CREATE TABLE `post_lists` (
 `id` int(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `users_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `code` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `date_posted` datetime NOT NULL,
 `date_updated` datetime NOT NULL,
 `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `cat_1` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `cat_3_code` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `details` varchar(10000) NOT NULL,
 `cat_2` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `cat_3` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
 KEY `date_posted` (`date_posted`),
 KEY `code` (`urlcode`),
 KEY `users_id_date_posted` (`users_id`,`date_posted`),
 KEY `title_date_posted` (`title`,`date_posted`),
 KEY `cat_1_date_posted` (`cat_1`,`date_posted`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=37 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

How many times will this table use ? Most of the time. This is the **advanced search** function so not just frequently as the **basic search** is.

**Edit #2**

Sorry! I forgot to add the `date_posted`.

This is how I actually will use the index.

Example Table

```
title | cat_1 | cat_2 | cat_3 | date_posted
```

My queries are simple:

1. **title**

   `SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE title LIKE %title% ORDER BY date_posted DESC`
2. **title** + **cat_1**

   `SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE title LIKE %title% AND cat_1 = 'cat_1' ORDER BY date_posted DESC`
3. **title** + **cat_1** + **cat_2**

   `SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE title LIKE %title% AND cat_1 = 'cat_1' AND cat_2 = 'cat_2' ORDER BY date_posted DESC`
4. **title** + **cat_1** + **cat_2** + **cat_3**

   `SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE title LIKE %title% AND cat_1 = 'cat_1' AND cat_2 = 'cat_2' AND cat_3 = 'cat_3' ORDER BY date_posted DESC`
5. **title** + **cat_1** + **cat_3**

   `SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE title LIKE %title% AND cat_1 = 'cat_1' and cat_3 = 'cat_3' ORDER BY date_posted DESC`
6. **title** + **cat_2**

   `SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE title LIKE %title% AND cat_2 = 'cat_2' ORDER BY date_posted DESC`
7. **title** + **cat_2** + **cat_3**

   `SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE title LIKE %title% AND cat_2 = 'cat_2' AND cat_3 = 'cat_3' ORDER BY date_posted DESC`
8. **title** + **cat_3**

   `SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE title LIKE %title% AND cat_3 = 'cat_3' ORDER BY date_posted DESC`
9. **cat_1**

   `SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE cat_1 = 'cat_1' ORDER BY date_posted DESC`
10. **cat_1** + **cat_2**

    `SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE cat_1 = 'cat_1' AND cat_2 = 'cat_2' ORDER BY date_posted DESC`
11. **cat_1** + **cat_2** + **cat_3**

    `SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE cat_1 = 'cat_1' AND cat_2 = 'cat_2' AND cat_3 = 'cat_3' ORDER BY date_posted DESC`
12. **cat_1** + **cat_3**

    `SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE cat_1 = 'cat_1' AND cat_3 = 'cat_3' ORDER BY date_posted DESC`
13. **cat_2**

    `SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE cat_2 = 'cat_2' ORDER BY date_posted DESC`
14. **cat_2** + **cat_3**

    `SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE cat_2 = 'cat_2' ORDER BY date_posted DESC`
15. **cat_3**

    `SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE cat_3 = 'cat_3' ORDER BY date_posted DESC`

How can I query this?

**Edit**

Hi, I read and searched about Full Text Search, and I am thinking to use it (in basic search) instead of `LIKE %wildcard%` and applying it to `title` and `details`, my problem is I want them to sort `ORDER BY date_posted DESC`, so should I add `date_posted` in Full Text Search or create a separate index?

Comment: common man , you need to provide more information on this. what query are you doing ? what is size of table ? structure of table ? how many times will this table use ?

Comment: can you please paste output of 'show create table **table_name**' . Can you please post explain plan of your query by doing EXPLAIN **your_query**

Comment: I am really interested on how you concluded that "*a query of **cat_3** will **NOT** use the index.*"

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ because I read that if I index a 3 column ex(col1, col2, col3), a query of col3 will not use the index.

Comment: Hello guys, I edited my question, I added all of my queries related to the index I wanted.

Comment: @DumbQuestion then why would an index on cat_2 use it? What's the difference between the second and third field? A cutoff at an arbitrary ordinal position?

Comment: I based my question and comment(s) from what I know, if I am wrong, please do tell me, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume by "use the index", you mean that the columns are referenced in a `WHERE` clause?

Your understanding of indexes is quite far off.

```
INDEX(`title`, `cat_1`, `cat_2`, `cat_3`, `date_posted`)
```

Cannot be used if you don't include some reference to `title`.  And some references to `title` won't work, such as:

```
WHERE `title` LIKE '%title%'
```

Certain other constructs work only for the last used column: "ranges" such as these

```
BETWEEN 22 AND 33
LIKE 'foo%'    -- note trailing wildcard, but not leading wildcard
```

In addition to the links already given, I proffer this one:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

Comment: +1 thanks! yes, you are right. thanks for the link, I saved it. Btw, I used the Full Text Search Index on my basic search instead of `%text%` wildcard.

Comment: Hi, I have a question, does `DELETE` statement uses an `index`? Thank you.

Comment: `DELETE` and `UPDATE` also use indexes when appropriate.  Think of it this way -- they have to locate the row before deleting or updating it.  Locating the row is essentially a `SELECT`.

Answer (score 1):

My full conclusion here is that you should spend some time learning about indexes on BTREE data structures. The implementation in MySQL isn't very complicated and the sharp edges are evidently unknown. I've added some resources to my original answer and if you're serious about the performance of this and future applications you write/optimise with MySQL you should do your homework. Feeding you the fish here will not help you longer term.

> ALTER TABLE table_name ADD INDEX advanced_query (`title`, `cat_1`, `cat_2`, `cat_3`)

Only filtering, aggregating or ordering involving the left most column will be valid for this index.

i.e.

> SELECT {cols} FROM {table_name} WHERE title = *something* and cat_1 BETWEEN *value* AND *value*;

Or

> SELECT {cols} FROM {table_name}  WHERE cat_1 in (*value*, *value*, *value*) ORDER BY title

If you want to learn more on MySQL indexing check out resources such as

https://www.percona.com/files/presentations/WEBINAR-tools-and-techniques-for-index-design.pdf

Indexing in general is well detailed by Markus Winand

http://use-the-index-luke.com

Your queries using

```
... LIKE '%value%' ...
```

are unable to use indexes because of the wild carding. You can switch to using FULLTEXT matching. The LIKE pattern is not scalable and will cause full table scans all the time.

Comment: Thanks, I edited my question, I added all of my queries related to the index I wanted.

Comment: Hi, I researched about Full Text Search, and I am thinking to use it (in basic search) instead of `LIKE %wildcard%` and applying it to `title` and `details`, my problem is I want them to sort `ORDER BY date_posted DESC`, so should I add `date_posted` in Full Text Search or create a separate index?

Answer (score 1):

SQL might use the index for any of the queries above, but it might not use them either. How SQL picks an index is more complex than what you have stated. For example SQL might decide that it's quicker to do a table scan than to do a key lookup and so ignore the index even if your criteria is just **TITLE**.

If you look at the query plan when you specify the following, if it uses the index then you'll have an Index Scan instead of an index Seek:

> a query of cat_1 will use the index.
>
> a query of cat_2 will use the index.
>
> a query of cat_3 will NOT use the index.

If it does use your index then it's because SQL has decided that it's still quicker to scan the index rather than scan the clustered key.

Comment: Then, how can I check if the index is working? Insert a 500 dummy data?

Comment: Thanks, I edited my question, I added all of my queries related to the index I wanted.

Comment: Check the query plan, you'll see an index scan instead of an index seek. For 2000 rows it may perform well enough to not matter.

Comment: Hi, I researched about Full Text Search, and I am thinking to use it (in basic search) instead of `LIKE %wildcard%` and applying it to `title` and `details`, my problem is I want them to sort `ORDER BY date_posted DESC`, so should I add `date_posted` in Full Text Search or create a separate index?